# How to get data from Excel Workbook using sql command from variable in SSIS

Tags: ssis

My requirement is to fetch data from excel source using sql command from variable. I used a variable and  assigned the below text to that variable.

**User::QRY**   = "SELECT slno,ra_bill,pname FROM" + @[User::SheetName] + "$A:S]"

I am getting the error as "Invalid SQL statement" the Variable QRY not evaluating the "SheetName" Variable.

Please advise how to solve.

Comment: Use the debugger and tell us what is the value of `User::QRY` when it gets executed and raises the error.

Comment: Is the error on the expression parsing or during execution? Do you need to pad your string with a leading space? FROM " + @[User::SheetName] + "$A:S]". Should be able to inspect variables and see the query during debugging.

Comment: Here I used two variable one is "User::QRY" and another one is "@[User::SheetName]". Here the QRY ="SELECT slno,ra_bill,pname FROM" + @[User::SheetName] + "$A:S]". While checking in run time the sheet name is not evaluated. The Query is showing as SELECT slno,ra_bill,pname FROM" + @[User::SheetName] + "$A:S]. So I am getting the error.